# elegant way of clearing an events

Tags: c#

i am implementing  a Buthon_Click Method, which as the name suggests is being used with an event onclick button.Now in order this method to do what i want i need to clear/unbind/unsubscribe the delegate attached to the `SystemEvents.SessionSwitch` event.The problem is that i want to do this without caring which method has been hooked up before.
For an example:

```
SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new SessionSwitchEventHandler(Methodx);
```

So what i am doing now is creating a foreach and going through all possibilities - 4 overall:

```
int [] array={1,2,3,4};


foreach (int n in array)
{
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch -= new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch1);
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch -= new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch2);
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch -= new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch3);
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch -= new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch4);
}
```

i find this peace of code a bit cumbersome and awkward , and i was wondering if there is a more "elegant" way of doing this something like just `SystemEvents.SessionSwitch == null` or similar which would wipe out all methods hooked up ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It depends who "owns" `SystemEvents.SessionSwitch`. In general, from outside you can't *set* the list of event handlers - you can only add or remove them. That's the level of encapsulation.

You should distinguish between *events* and any variable which may happen to be the backing store for an event. Events only support subscription and removal. See my [article on events and delegates](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for more information.

Note that your existing code can be a little tidier already:

```
foreach (int n in array)
{
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch -= SystemEvents_SessionSwitch1;
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch -= SystemEvents_SessionSwitch2;
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch -= SystemEvents_SessionSwitch3;
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch -= SystemEvents_SessionSwitch4;
}
```

... although as you're not using `n` here, it's not really clear why you're looping.

Comment: `SystemEvents` is part of the framework (in `Microsoft.Win32`).

Answer (score 0):

One feature (among others) that sets events apart from delegates is this very restriction to **+= and -= only for outsiders**. You cannot do any other operation on an event other then these two if you don't own the event.

The class that owns the event can ofcourse do :

```
SystemEvents.SessionSwitch==null; // only allowable to the owner of SessionSwitch
```